# Why I am unable to fetch FSL package objects in SOQL query from Visual force Java script?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to fetch the list of objects using javascript. I am able to fetch the `Account` or `Contact` standard object but not `WorkOrderLineItem` object. What could be the reason for the same?

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="/soap/ajax/16.0/connection.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/soap/ajax/16.0/apex.js"></script>

<script> 
    window.onload = function(){
        sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!$Api.Session_ID}';
        var agmtArray = sforce.connection.query("Select Id from WorkOrderLineItem limit 2");
        var records = agmtArray.getArray("records");
        alert('>>'+records);     
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you change the ajax version and try? Seems like you are using much older veriosn for the same.URL : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_connecting.htm

Comment: I tried with 47.0 too but it did not work out for me.

Comment: Hey, I got it.. Thank you :)

Comment: Any error you are getting in browser console or any debug log?

Comment: No, I changed it to 46 version and it worked perfectly.